# Check if array is in array and get match in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array and wanted to check if an array is in that associative  array, If yes, I want to get the matching array.

My associative array look something like this:

```
 $assoc_array = array(
  array(
   'firstname' => 'John',
   'lastname' => 'Doe',
   'age' => 26
  ),
  array(
   'firstname' => 'Sophia',
   'lastname' => 'Smith',
   'age' => 30
  )
 );
```

Then if I want to check this array:

```
 $array = array(
   'firstname' => 'John',
   'lastname' => 'Doe'
 );
```

It would give me this result:

```
array(
 'firstname' => 'John',
 'lastname' => 'Doe',
 'age' => 26
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your inner arrays have no keys associated with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you loop the array and use array_intersect it will return first and lastname.
If there is no match it returns empty array.

This means we can do an easy if on the match if that is true then add the subarray to your new array.

```
foreach($assoc_array as $sub){
    $match = array_intersect($sub, $array);
    if($match) $new[] = $sub;
}
var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/enaXb

Or condense it to:

```
foreach($assoc_array as $sub){
    if(array_intersect($sub, $array)) $new[] = $sub;
}
var_dump($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet.array_intersect_assoc should do the trick -

```
<?php
$haystack = array(
    array(
       'firstname' => 'John',
       'lastname' => 'Doe',
       'age' => 26
    ),
    array(
       'firstname' => 'Sophia',
       'lastname' => 'Smith',
       'age' => 30
    )
);

$needle = array(
   'firstname' => 'John',
   'lastname' => 'Doe'
);

function returnMatchValues($haystack = array(), $needle = array()) {
    ksort($needle);
    foreach ($haystack as $key=>$val) {
            
    if(count($needle) === count(array_intersect_assoc ($val, $needle))) {
        return $haystack[$key];
    }
}
return [];
}

print_r(returnMatchValues($haystack, $needle)); 


?>
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

```html
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

Link : https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_intersect